# How to flash AOSP 11 on to Redmi 6A?

Tags: fastboot, aosp

I've successfully compiled aosp_arm64 and now I'd like to know how to flash it on to my device.

I couldn't do it with command `fastboot flashall -w` as it outputs this:

```
--------------------------------------------
Bootloader Version...: cactus-0deb5cf-20191022185025-20200508231234
Baseband Version.....: MOLY.LR12A.R2.MP.V66.P18
Serial Number........: 0f70e4b47d2b
--------------------------------------------
Checking 'product'                                 FAILED

Device product is 'cactus'.
Update requires ''.

fastboot: error: requirements not met!
```

I'm guessing I need to flash images individually, but I'm really unsure what to do.

Comment: AOSP will most likely not work because AOSP is not a generic distribution like RedHat or Fedora. If you want to build a ROM yourself you first need a device tree matching your device. As your device is most likely Treble compliant you could try a Generic System Image (GSI). Besides that I would recommend to learn more about Android and it's specialties.